# Remove Namespace and add new elements while copying XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have a simple xml that looks like

```
<ns0:AAA xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ITSVersion="XML_1.0">
    <ns0:id extension="USER_TYPE"/>
    <ns0:bb>SOME VALUE</ns0:bb>
    <ns0:cc>OTHER VALUE</ns0:cc>
</ns0:AAA>
```

I am trying to add a "wrapper" element around a top-level element `AAA` and also remove the name-space prefix `ns0` from the above xml. Lastly add new elements after the `<ns0:bb>SOME VALUE</ns0:bb>`.

I have tried building an xslt for that, but somehow I could not remove the `ns0` prefix when copying and the new elements that I have added are added with `xmlns=""`. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:urn="http://www.example.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:if test="urn:id[@extension='USER_TYPE']">
         <xsl:element name="WRAPPER" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                
                <xsl:element name="cred">
                    <xsl:attribute name="user">test123</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="password">
                            <xsl:attribute name="root">n</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    
    <xsl:if test="urn:Id[@extension='ASSET_TYPE']">
        <xsl:element name="WRAPPER" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of the xslt looks like

```
<WRAPPER xmlns="http://www.example.com" ITSVersion="XML_1.0">
    <ns0:id xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" extension="USER_TYPE"/>
    <ns0:bb xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">SOME VALUE</ns0:bb>
    <ns0:cc xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">OTHER VALUE</ns0:cc>
    <cred xmlns="" user="test123"><password root="n"/></cred>
</WRAPPER>
```

As you can see the `WRAPPER` element is added correctly, but all the other elements have the prefix and also the xmlns attributes, I want to remove the prefix `ns0` and `xmlns` attributes from those elements. And the new element that I am adding `cred` shows up with an empty `xmlns`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in Advance for any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "remove namespace" actually requires renaming. That means you cannot use the *identity transform* template which preserves the processed nodes *as is*.

Try instead something along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>      
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <WRAPPER>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <cred user="test123">
            <password root="n"/>
        </cred>
    </WRAPPER>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WRAPPER>
   <id extension="USER_TYPE"/>
   <bb>SOME VALUE</bb>
   <cc>OTHER VALUE</cc>
   <cred user="test123">
      <password root="n"/>
   </cred>
</WRAPPER>
```

Note the use of [literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element).

Comment: Thanks a lot! can the `cred` element location be changed i.e. can it be added after the `bb` element in the same copy operation or does it have to be done in a separate template?

Comment: You can do `<xsl:apply-templates select=ns0:id | ns0:bb" />` first, then add the `cred` element and then `<xsl:apply-templates select=ns0:cc" />`. But this requires that you declare the `ns0`namespace in your stylesheet and use `exclude-result-prefixes` to avoid passing it to the output.

Comment: I tried your solution, actually somehow it's stripping the original top-level `AAA` element, any idea how to have all the elements from the input XML show up (wrapped in `WRAPPER` element) in the output?

Comment: I thought that's  you what you wanted. If not, then add the wrapper in a template matching `/`. Or add an `xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` instruction to the existing template, within the `WRAPPER` element.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry I didn't realize that my XSLT was also not including the top-level element from XML. But your suggestion works fine, all good now! Thanks :)